# Having issues with my TFS 2013 Installation after the previous installation expires

Tags: tfs

I have previously Install the TFS 2013 pre-lease,create team project everything was working fine util the license expired,giving me only one option that is to uninstall and reinstall.
I Now install new instance of tfs 2013,I created a report server do all the configuration,tested the url and it works fine.But when i try to configure the TFS In a stadard single server mode. i keep getting error when its configuring the report. Am new to this Technology but i did not face such issues during my first installation.The report server and the tfs are both on the same server.But the database am using is on a name instance.
here is the error i keep getting:

```
TF255324: The database that you specified cannot be created because a database already exists with that name. The database name is: Tfs_Warehouse. The server hosting the database is: URANUS\dev.  You can use one of the three following options.
• If the database is a valid database from a previous version of Team Foundation Server and you want to upgrade it, you must use the Upgrade from Previous Version Wizard.
• If the database is a valid database from the current version of Team Foundation Server and you want to use it, you must use the Application Tier Only Wizard.
• If the database is a valid database used by another Team Foundation Server instance and you wish to create a new database, you must use the advanced wizard to supply a different SQL Server instance or database label.
```

For more information, see the readme file and the installation guide for Team Foundation.

```
The following database already exists, but cannot be used as part of this installation of Team Foundation Server: Tfs_Configuration. The database is hosted on the following server: URANUS\dev. You can manually delete or rename this database before you continue, but it is not required. If you do not, the database will be renamed as part of the installation process.

TF400080: Your system does not have the recommended amount of system memory  available: 10 GB. While SharePoint 2013 with Team Foundation Server can operate with less than this amount of memory, the performance will be degraded. Upgrade your system memory to at least the recommended minimum for optimal performance.

TF255142: Windows Firewall is not enabled. If you enable Windows Firewall after configuring Team Foundation Server, you must add exceptions for ports used by Team Foundation Server to Windows Firewall.

Enabling legacy trace logging for SharePoint. Upon completion of installation or upgrade, legacy trace logging will be returned to its original status.
```

Comment: Are you upgrading? If so you must use the upgrade wizard. Are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to upgrade your TFS 2013, by using  `http://aka.ms/TFSUpgradeWeekend.`

link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2013/08/23/register-now-for-team-foundation-server-2013-upgrade-weekend.aspx

Remark : Enter your credentials on MSDN